# Flex 3: List item selection color alpha

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex3, selection, alpha

Is it possible to set alpha for a list item selection color (based on Flex 3)?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do out-of-the-box AFAIK however this is a great solution that's easy to implement:

http://natescodevault.com/2009/08/01/add-alpha-transparency-to-your-datagrid-using-styleabledatagrid/